# R Horizontal Stacked Percentage Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a task using GGplot that I'm stuck with.

Im asked to horizontally plot the percentage of income provenance per individual with the following data.frame :

```
PersonalID <- c(1,2,3)
Stock.Return <- c(20,10,70)
Salary <- c(90,25,40)
Bond.Return <- c(16,10,7)
MyDat <- data.frame(PersonalID, Stock.Return, Salary, Bond.Return)
```

[And it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCqT3.jpg)

As i understand i'm supposed to use facet_wrap , I have X and Y but no fill so i'm a bit lost.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. The key in `ggplot2` to get the maximum power of its functions is first reshaping to long and after that you can design the plot. Here the code for the plot, using `tidyverse` functions for data process and `ggplot2`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
MyDat %>% pivot_longer(-PersonalID) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(PersonalID),y=value,fill=name,group=name))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',color='black',position='fill')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))+
  coord_flip()+
  xlab('PersonalID')+ylab('Percentage')+
  ggtitle('Income distribution per person')
```

Output:

[image]